# How to get 2 letter country code from string in php

Tags: php

I want to get the 2 letter country codes from a string in PHP.

For example:

1. Lazada-SG-IOS-Non Incent_IMRO33811 - SG
2. Cobo Launcher Android BR,IN,ID,IQ,US Incent(Capped) - BR,IN,ID,IQ,US
3. Beintoo-Jumia-Andoid-NG-Blended Incent_IMRO27929 - NG
4. Brave Frontier - Android AU/CA/US/UK Incent CPE - AU,CA,US,UK
5. MU Origin Android KR Non incent - KR,MU
6. GS Shop Android| IMRO37088| KR - Non Incent - KR
7. Zalando_DK_android_nonincent_IMRO35303 - DK

Comment: I think you need to be more precise about what you want. Do you know what the string might look like? Do you want any country code anywhere in the string? Why shouldn't `Mu` be included, when it is the country code for Mauritius?

Comment: mu origin is product... we cannot guess by program its country code or product. lets consider it as Country code

Comment: What makes it a product and not a country code? Is it something about the position in the string? Unless you give us some kind of rule for when things are products and when things are country codes it is *literally impossible* to solve this problem. No one here reads minds.

Comment: There are no rules .... I have to find the country code from product name. Some times it may also happens two letter word is in string but may not a actual country. But we cannot decide programatically wheater it is country or product . I DONT WANT TO COMPARE COUNTRIES STORED IN DB

Comment: And what about `GS` Don't you need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will return an array with any country codes that in upper cases with a non alphanumeric character on each side:

```
function getCountryCodes($input) {

    //An array with all the country codes.
    //You will have to add more yourself.
    static $country_codes = array('BR','IN','ID','IQ','US','MU','KR');

    //Creates a regex pattern like ""/(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?:BR|IN|ID|IQ|US|MU|KR)(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9])/".
    static $pattern = '/(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?:' . implode('|', $country_codes) . ')(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9])/';

    //Find any matches for the pattern.
    preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $matches);

    //Return the result.
    return $matches[0];

}
```

Let's break down the regex:

- `(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9])`: Lookbehind for anything not alphanumeric.
- `(?:BR|IN|ID|IQ|US|MU|KR)`: Match any of the `|` delimitered alternatives, but do not capture into a subgroup (due to the `?:`).
- `(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9])`: Lookahead for anything not alphanumeric.

For a full list of country codes, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2).

Answer (score 0):

For every row, do

```
preg_match_all('/\b([A_Z]{2}([^A_Za-z]([A_Z]{2})))*\b/', $string, $sets, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$array = array();
foreach ($sets as $matches) {
    $array = array_merge($array, preg_split('/[^A-Z]/', $matches[1]));
}
```

You get an array of possible present country codes. This array can then be checked against a list of valid country codes.

Comment: Won't this capture two letter words that are not country codes, like `AK`, as well?

Comment: Yes, it would match any two letter capitalized chars.